# Lagrange multipliers with constraints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to get the max and min of the function $f(x,y,z)$ and $h(x,y,z)$ is the constraint. I have done the below steps. Are the value of my points correct for $x,y,z$? If so how do I proceed to find the max and min.

$$f(x,y,z)=xyz$$
$$h(x,y,z)=x+y+z^2=5$$

$$f_x=h_x\lambda \implies yz=\lambda$$
$$f_y=h_y\lambda \implies xz=\lambda$$
$$f_z=h_z\lambda \implies xy=2z\lambda$$

$$\begin{cases} x=2,\\ y=2, \\z=\pm 1,-1. \end{cases}$$

Comment: what is $g$? clarify your notations concerning derivatives

Comment: sorry should be hx rather than gx

Comment: i found 2 points but there should be 6? is there an efficient way to find all points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've found the points correctly.  To find the maximum and minimum values of $f$ subject to the constraint, evaluate $f$ at these points:

$$f(2,2,1)=4$$

$$f(2,2,-1)=-4$$

So 4 is the maximum value and $-4$ the minimum.

Comment: i ran through a check at http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/equations/solve/advanced.jsp and found out that there are more points. can't seem to figure where did it went wrong

Comment: The system of equations does have some more solutions if you allow $\lambda=0$, but that will force two out of the other three variables to be zero, giving $f$ a value of 0, which lies between $-4$ and 4.